# How to add prefix to all the elements of List efficiently?

Tags: java, list, collections, set

I have a List in which I need to add a prefix in all the elements of my list.

Below is the way I am doing it by iterating the list and then adding it. Is there any other better way to do it? Any one-two liner that can do the same stuff?

```
private static final List<DataType> DATA_TYPE = getTypes();

public static LinkedList<String> getData(TypeFlow flow) {
    LinkedList<String> paths = new LinkedList<String>();
    for (DataType current : DATA_TYPE) {
        paths.add(flow.value() + current.value());
    }
    return paths;
}
```

I need to return LinkedList since I am using some methods of LinkedList class like `removeFirst`.

I am on Java 7 as of now.

Comment: Use Java 8 Streams with `map`.

Comment: I am using Java 7 unfortunately.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For one liners, use Java 8 Streams :

```
List<String> paths = DATA_TYPE.stream().map(c -> flow.value() + c.value()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you must produce a `LinkedList`, you should use a different Collector.

Comment: I am using Java 7 unfortunately.

Comment: @user1950349 In Java 7 your implementation looks as short as it can be.

Answer (score 4):

Your implementation looks ok, but if you want something different, try this:

```
public static List<String> getData(final TypeFlow flow) {
    return new AbstractList<String>() {
        @Override
        public String get(int index) {
            return flow.value()+DATA_TYPE.get(index).value();
        }

        @Override
        public int size() {
            return DATA_TYPE.size();
        }
    };
}
```

This way you create a "virtual list" which does not actually contains data, but computes it on the fly.

Comment: What is the difference between your version and my version here? What do you mean by virtual list here?

Comment: It does not take additional memory except a constant amount like 20-30 bytes. And it does not perform any string concatenation until you start traversing this list. Your version creates all the prefixed strings and stores them into memory in advance which takes O(n) addtional memory where n is the `DATA_TYPE` list size. In your case that's probably doesn't matter, but if you have millions of entries in `DATA_TYPE`, the memory footprint might differ significantly.

Comment: Very interesting implementation!